# How do I prevent FOSUserbundle from duplicating roles in Symfony3.3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, fosuserbundle

I'm new to programming and decided to start PHP using the Symfony framework.

My aim is to have a user system where there is a many to many relationship between Users and their Roles. Ideally, I'd like roles stored in their own table.

I've managed to set these up but do have an issue here. 
Whenever FOSUserBundle creates a user and adds a role, my code would now create a duplicate entry in the Roles table. For instance:

---

*I create a user: User1, and assign the role "ROLE_ADMIN"* - A "ROLE_ADMIN" record is created in the roles Table.

*I create a user: User2 and assign the same role* - Instead of using the existing ROLE_ADMIN record, a new record is created.

---

I thought of having the Entity Manager go through the roles table before creating a new role, however, as I've read in other responses here on stackoverflow, this is heavily discouraged. Other answers have also discouraged using a service within an entity

Here is my code for both entities (I'm new to programming forgive the mistakes)

**User.php**

```
<?php
namespace ShagCore\MemberBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="member_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="member_user_role")
     */
    protected $userRoles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->userRoles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addRole($roleStr)
    {
        //get the role as a string, loop through the $this->roles (Role Objects)
        //ensure that this role name isn't there, THEN add it as a new Role Obj 
        //to the $this->roles array

        $roleStr = strtoupper($roleStr);   

        $currRoles = [];

        foreach($this->userRoles as $userRole) {
            $currRoles[] = $userRole->getRole();
        }

        if(!in_array($roleStr, $currRoles)) {
            $role = new Role();
            $role->setRole($roleStr);
            $this->userRoles[] = $role;
        }
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        $roles = array();
        foreach($this->userRoles as $role) {
            $roles[] = $role->getRole();
        }

        return array_unique($roles);
    }
}
```

**Role.php**

```
<?php
namespace ShagCore\MemberBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;


//TODO: removeRole()

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="member_role")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=TRUE, length=100)
     */
    protected $role;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="userRoles", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=TRUE)
     */
    protected $description;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //parent::__construct();
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Add user
     *
     * @param \ShagCore\MemberBundle\Entity\User $user
     *
     * @return Role
     */
    public function addUser(\ShagCore\MemberBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->users[] = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove user
     *
     * @param \ShagCore\MemberBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function removeUser(\ShagCore\MemberBundle\Entity\User $user)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get users
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `new Role`, hence a new Role Object is created (and persisted). If you don't want that you have to make addRole take a `Role` object as parameter and add that to it's ArrayCollection. This is generally part of some kind of UserManager.

Comment: agree with ccKep just to be a bit more clear: make addRole take a EXISTING Role object

Comment: I considered this, the snag I was hitting is that the Roles are provided by the FOSUserBundle as a string, and not a Role object.

Comment: Exact, it's just a string in the database, not object.
if you use FOS User bundle, no need to create Role entity.
You fetch the role with user->getRole() I believe..